# checking wether a hashmap has items or not?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

What is wrong with the statement `if (!adjacentNodes.get(nodeId).isEmpty())` in the below code?

Such statement leads to the following message:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

```
package IN.company;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class DiffusionModels {
    public int ICModel(int[] seedSet, HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> adjacentNodes, double p) {
        HashSet<Integer> infected = new HashSet();
        HashSet<Integer> recentlyInfected = new HashSet();
...

        while (recentlyInfected.size() > 0) {
            HashSet<Integer> nextActivator = new HashSet<>();
            if (!recentlyInfected.isEmpty()) {
                for (Integer nodeId : recentlyInfected) {
                        if (!adjacentNodes.get(nodeId).isEmpty()) {
                            HashSet<Integer> neighborsOfNode =adjacentNodes.get(nodeId) ;
                            for (Integer nodeNeighbor : neighborsOfNode) {
                                if ((Math.random() <= p)&& !(infected.contains(nodeNeighbor))) {
                                    nextActivator.add(nodeNeighbor);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            infected.addAll(recentlyInfected);
            recentlyInfected.clear();
            recentlyInfected.addAll(nextActivator);
        }
        return infected.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the expression you designate generates a `NullPointerException` then it is surely because `adjacentNodes.get(nodeId)` returns `null`.  Note in particular that `null` is an altogether different beast from a non-null reference to an empty `Map`.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I fix it? I check this issue with isEmpty function, is it wrong?

Comment: @Timothy Truckle, thank you, but that topic would not be useful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This beacause adjacentNodes is null,which result to NPE.Before that line try to print the values of adjacentNodes.Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I know it but how can I fix it?

Comment: !adjacentNodes.isEmpty()  or != null

Answer (score 1):

Try this `if (adjacentNodes.get(nodeId) != null && !adjacentNodes.get(nodeId).isEmpty()) {`

Answer (score 0):

> I would be grateful if anyone help me and explain what is the problem of this statement:
>
> ```
> if (!adjacentNodes.get(nodeId).isEmpty())
> ```
>
> This statement leads to "java.lang.NullPointerException"

According to the code you posted either `adjacentNodes` is **null** or it does not contain the key currently referenced by `nodeId`.

You have to check that `adjacentNodes` is not **null** before that line.

If `adjacentNodes` is not **null** you should use the `getOrDefault()`  method of Java8's `Map` class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-)

```
if(!adjacentNodes.getOrDefault(nodeId, Collections.emptySet()).isEmpty())){ //...
```